# Bootstrap hover and toggle collapse menu not working in rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I am working through [this guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lets-create-an-intermediate-level-ruby-on-rails-application-d7c6e997c63f) and am up to [this section](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/lets-create-an-intermediate-level-ruby-on-rails-application-d7c6e997c63f#fc51) but for some reason when I view on mobile, clicking on the mobile hamburger menu doesn't show the menu, and also when on desktop the hover doesn't work on the `dropdown-toggle` either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is `_navigation.html.erb`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- Elements visible all the time -->
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <%= render 'layouts/navigation/header' %>
      </div><!-- col-sm-7 -->

      <!-- Elements collapses on smaller devices -->
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <%= render 'layouts/navigation/collapsible_elements' %>
      </div><!-- col-sm-5 -->

    </div><!-- row -->
  </div><!-- container -->
</nav>
```

Here is `_header.html.erb`

```
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible-content" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <%= link_to 'User Logins', root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
</div>
```

and here is `_collapsable-elements.html.erb`

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapsible-content">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <li class="dropdown pc-menu">
        <a id="user-settings" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <span id="user-name"><%= current_user.name %></span>
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_registration_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="mobile-menu">
        <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_registration_path %>
      </li>
      <li class="mobile-menu">
        <%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
      </li>

    <% else # user not signed it %>
      <li ><%= link_to 'Login', login_path %></li>
      <li ><%= link_to 'Signup', signup_path %></li>
    <% end # if user is signed it %>
  </ul>
</div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
```

I think i've included everything needed to figure this out. If I missed anything please let me know!

Thanks :)

**Edit:**

I forgot to include the `navigation.scss`

```
body {
 margin-top: 50px;
}

nav {
  .navbar-header {
    width: 100%;
    button, .navbar-brand {
      transition: opacity 0.15s;
    }
    button {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    button:hover, .navbar-brand:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
    }
  }
  .col-sm-5, .col-sm-7 {
    padding: 0;
  }
}

.navbar-default, .navbar-toggle:focus, .collapsed, button.navbar-toggle {
  background: $navbarColor !important;
  border: none;
  a {
    color: white !important;
  }
}

.pc-menu {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.mobile-menu {
  i {
    color: white;
  }
  ul {
    padding: 0px;
  }
  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 25px !important;
  }
  a:hover {
    background: white !important;
    color: black !important;
    i {
      color: black;
    }
  }
}

.icon-bar {
  background-color: white !important;
}

.active a {
  background: $navbarColor !important;
  border-bottom: solid 5px white;
}

.dropdown-toggle, .dropdown-menu {
  background: $navbarColor !important;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: black !important;
  background: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this file app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Try to remove this line

```
//= require turbolinks
```

and remove `"data-turbolinks-track" => true from javascript_include_tag.`